# Is Money earned outside India transferred in NRO a/c instead of NRE a/c taxable in India?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, income

Money is transferred to NRO account but was to be transferred to NRE account is such income taxable in India

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are an NRI from tax perspective. Any income NRI earns is non-taxable in India. It is irrelevant whether the funds were transferred to India or not and whether they were transferred to NRO or NRE account is not relevant.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions and any  guidelines u can share regarding or relating RBI or new budget relating foriegn income...

Comment: There is no change to taxation of foreign income in new budget. Read the India Income Tax on Govt website for more info on current taxation